# iOS drawing pixels in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, opengl-es, drawing

I have an 2D array of RGB values (or any such data container) that I need to write to UIView that is currently displayed to the user. An example would be — while using the capture output from the camera, I run some algorithms to identify objects and then highlight them using custom defined RGB pixels.

What is the best way to do this as this whole thing is done in real-time every 10 frames per second for example?

Answer (score 2):

Use the method below to create a UIImage from your 2D array.  You can then display this image using a UIImageView.

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromArray:(void *)array width:(unsigned int)width height:(unsigned int)height {
    /*
     Assuming pixel color values are 8 bit unsigned

     You need to create an array that is in the format BGRA (blue,green,red,alpha).  
     You can achieve this by implementing a for-loop that sets the values at each index. 
     I have not included a for-loop in this example because it depends on how the values are stored in your input 2D array.  
     You can set the alpha value to 255.
    */
    unsigned char pixelData[width * height * 4];

    // This is where the for-loop would be

    void *baseAddress = &pixelData;

    size_t bytesPerRow = width * 4;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: I know this is very late, but when I set my alpha, it's interpreted either as 0 or as 255. If I set it to 100 for instance, it's interpreted as 0. Any idea ?